# angular2-datetimepicker not closing on outside click

Tags: angular, npm

I am using , ***angular2-datetimepicker*** but could not close it on outside click,
hence I  added ***click outside*** functionality to the div holding it.
but ***popover*** property in angular2-datetimepicker toggles based on click due to which sometimes I need twice click on date widget which is not even all time, so to solve I thought of accessing **popover** variable and keep it true always.

But unable to do that. Please help me.

this is how I am using it:

```
<angular2-date-picker (onDateSelect)="onDateSelect($event)"
    [(ngModel)]="dateTime" 
    [settings]="settings" >
    </angular2-date-picker>
```

where

```
 settings = {
        bigBanner: false,
        timePicker: false,
        format: 'dd-MM-yyyy',
        defaultOpen: false
        };
```

And I am manually closing using below code when user clicks outside.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('wc-date-popover')['style'].display = 'none';
```

Need help how I can avoid twice click or toggling of ***popover*** property of  ***angular2-datetimepicker***

Comment: I think closing on outside click is supported natively. No need to handle it. You can check the [examples](https://cuppalabs.github.io/angular2-datetimepicker)

Comment: @yazantahha, Thanks for quick reply, I verified link you shared, but in Github HTML code of it has **closepopover()** method  where as I am not finding that in my node module package code,  I am using "angular2-datetimepicker": "^1.1.1".

Comment: I actually suggest to go with other updated component as the last update was 3 years ago. You can check `@angular-material-components/datetime-picker` if you have the Angular Material, or `@danielmoncada/angular-datetime-picker` (There are many others)